# list comprehension and item with chinese character

Tags: python, list, csv

I have the following code which will grab some data with Chinese character from a website.

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.hkcpast.net/cpast_homepage/xyzbforms/BetMatchDetails.asp?tBetDate=2016/9/11"

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

for a in soup.find_all('html'):
    a.decompose()

list = []
for row in soup.find_all('tr'):
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    for col in cols:
        if len(col) > 0:
            list.append(col.text.encode('utf-8').strip())
```

For now the result is like this:

```
[1, x, y, z, 2, x, y, z, 3, x, y, z]
```

My question is I want to create some sublists from the list, which the is separated by a number (1, 2, 3, 4 ,5 . .. . .)

so that the result will be like this:

```
[1, x, y, z]
[2, x, y, z]
[3, x, y, z]
```

the ultimate goal of this is to write each sublist as a row in a csv file. Does it make sense to first separate the list into each entry and then write into a csv file?

Comment: Please stick to *one issue* per question. Both issues you describe are too vague to answer however. Perhaps you can provide us with some sample input and expected output for the first? The latter is just an encoding issue; you encoded your data to UTF-8, so when printing or listing you'll see `\xhh` byte representations in the output. That is normal.

Comment: I have edited the question so that only one question left that is. How could I create sublists from a list with certain requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The literal translation of your code would look like:

```
list = []
for row in soup.find_all('tr'):
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    for col in cols:
        if len(col) = 0:
            continue  # Save some indentation
        txt = col.text.encode('utf-8').strip()
        try:
           _ = int(txt)
           # txt is an int.  Append new sub-list
           list.append( [txt] )
        except ValueError:
           # txt is not an int, append it to the end of previous sub-list
           list[-1].append(txt)
```

(Note that this will fail horribly if the first entry is not an int!)

However, I suspect you actually want to create a new sub-list for each row in the table.